# Compile-time arithmetic via generic types in Rust, similar to C++?

Tags: c++, rust

I'm just learning Rust and would like to write code that uses generic types to perform compile-time arithmetic.

For example, in C++ I can write the following code ([on Goldbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8n3Ms3zKd)):

```
#include <iostream>

template <int X>
struct Test {
    constexpr static int x = X;
};

template <int X1, int X2>
auto operator+(const Test<X1>&, const Test<X2>&) {
    return Test<X1 + X2>{};
}

int main() {
    const Test<4> a{};
    const Test<6> b{};
    const auto c = a + b;
    std::cout << c.x << '\n'; // prints 10
}
```

I try to write analogous code in Rust ([on Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a2fbf8e58269bf37281b11cb1a5fc00)):

```
use std::ops::Add;

pub struct Test<const X: u8>;

impl<const X: u8> Test<X> {
    pub fn x(&self) -> u8 { X }
}

impl<const X1: u8, const X2: u8> Add<Test<X2>> for Test<X1> {
    type Output = Test<{X1 + X2}>;
    fn add(self, rhs: Test<X2>) -> Test<{X1 + X2}> {
        Test::<{X1 + X2}>{}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Test<4> = Test{};
    let b: Test<6> = Test{};
    let c = a + b;
    println!("{}", c::x());
}
```

...but this won't compile, since `generic parameters may not be used in const operations`. Is this kind of thing simply impossible to do with Rust, or is there another strategy I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, but `const` generics aren't complete yet, so it currently requires a nightly compiler and an explicitly enabled feature:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![allow(incomplete_features)]

use std::ops::Add;

pub struct Test<const X: u8>;

impl<const X: u8> Test<X> {
    pub fn x(&self) -> u8 { X }
}

impl<const X1: u8, const X2: u8> Add<Test<X2>> for Test<X1> where [(); (X1 + X2) as usize]: {
    type Output = Test<{X1 + X2}>;
    fn add(self, _rhs: Test<X2>) -> Test<{X1 + X2}> {
        Test::<{X1 + X2}>{}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Test<4> = Test{};
    let b: Test<6> = Test{};
    let c = a + b;
    let Test::<10> = c;
    println!("{}", c.x());
}
```

[(Permalink to playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ac3f5b4f6a275ce3f69c5cb7d4b06dcb)

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain the reasoning for the added `where` clause?

Comment: @NickFP Rust (at least currently) requires every generic constants on which calculations are performed to repeat the computation explicitly within the signature. This is because evaluation of constants may fail (e.g. the addition may overflow), and thus, adding an constant expression using a generic constant to a function is a breaking change. Rust aims to requires (almost) every potential breaking change to be expressed explicitly in the signature, so you can update the function body without fears.